# zipalign fail on apk with many files

Tags: android, apk

I have two APK. Their name different by one word. One APK zipalign successfully finished but another fail with error:
Error while running zipalign: Unable to open as zip archive

This is not path issue, first APK signed just fine. Apk contains about 120 000 files and weight about 600 mb.

Comment: Have you tried unzipping you apk using another software?

Comment: Yes unzipped just fine. Also tried zip -FF.

Comment: When I deleted some files and leave about 60 000 zipalign work fine.

Comment: I guess most of these files are images. Why can't you load them dynamically when they are needed rather than packaging them all up in an apk?

Comment: Our client want offline application :(

Comment: Can you not Zip all the images and put them in your asset folder and then unzip them when you need them on the phone?

Comment: Not bad idea, but I used crosswalk and HTML+js. Many files is the result of using tiles to display big JPG's. I resize tile from 256x256 to 512x512 and this is solve my problem.